# Return distinct value inside array to put inside select tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I have successfully returned value of the database and put it inside the `<select> & <option>` tag in HTML. I cannot use `DISTINCT` in SQL query because the code for the backend is inside the API of the project.

so I try to use javascript to return only the distinct value of the `<select>` tag.

I found and tried this code but the `<select>` tag is empty.

`$scope.test_ = [{"id":"1", "name":"alex", "id":"2", "name":"cedie", , 
   "id":"3", "name":"alex"}]`

```
var list = $scope.test_.filter((x,i,a) => a.indexOf(x) == i);
```

No results returned cause of this.

Regards

Comment: What sort of object is `test_`, is it a plain array?

Comment: @CertainPerformance i have edited the question sir and attached the data inside the array. thanks

Comment: Objects should not have duplicate key names, but regardless, the code in your question appears to result in `list` holding a single object, it's not empty?

Comment: I guess with distinct, you mean distinct names? So you want the values `{"id":"1", "name":"alex"}` and `{"id":"3", "name":"alex"}` to result in just `"Alex"` being logged?

Comment: @CertainPerformance It is empty sir.

Comment: @MichielDral Yes sir. That's it.

Comment: But they're not distinct -- we have here an array with a single object, with any number of 'id' and 'name' options. I can't even guess what that would do. If that's what the backend is giving you, fire your java guys.

Comment: Using your code, it's not empty. https://jsfiddle.net/9L0fqb7o/

Comment: If you have this: `[{"id":"1", "name":"alex", "id":"2", "name":"cedie", , 
   "id":"3", "name":"alex"}]`, then you have one object. If you have this instead: `[{id:"1", "name":"alex"},{"id":"2","name":"cedie"},{"id":"3","name":"alex"}]` then you can filter THAT.

Comment: @Snowmonkey how to do that sir?? can you give me an example for me to solve the problem?

Comment: @Snowmonkey , I have seen the value of the array, and the value returned is like that you have sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close, but the code

```
var list = $scope.test_.filter((x,i,a) => a.indexOf(x) == i);
```

Will only look for the exact same values. Now, the objects in your array are actually unique, as they have differing `"id"` properties. (and would otherwise most likely still have different object identities but that is for another time)

Now a way to make it test against the name only, would be to instead of `.indexOf(x)`, use `.findIndex(y => y.name === x.name)` like this:

```
var list = $scope.test_.filter((x,i,a) => a.findIndex(y => y.name === x.name) == i);
```

I hope the code is self-explanatory enough, but let me know if it isn't :)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks Sir :)

Comment: I set this up on a repl, to see if it was, in fact that easy. And by golly, Michiel, very well done! Here's the repl, in case others want to hammer on it: https://repl.it/@TobiasParent/FilterArrayOfObjectsForUnique

Comment: @Snowmonkey I was actually surprised myself as well, as I normally "just" use Lodash's `uniqBy`, but I feel bad answering something here with "Just use this library" so I tried expanding on his attempt... learning something new every day I guess :) Also thanks for the repl.it!